# parallel transport_covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $u(s,t) $ be smooth and $X(t) $ vector field along $u(s_0,t) $. 
Denote with $P_s= P_s( u(s,t), u(s_0,t))$ parallel transport in $s$ direction along $u(s,t) $ from $u(s_0,t) $ to $u(s,t) $. Does the following hold:

$$ \nabla_t P_s X(t) = P_s \nabla_t X(t) $$

Comment: I beleive that it is true, and I would justify it as follows: Let $ V_1(s,t) = \nabla_s P_s X(t) $ and $ V_2(s,t) = P_s \nabla_t X(t) $. Then we have $$ V_s(s_0, t) = V_2(s_0,t) $$ and also $ \nabla_s V_1(s,t) = \nabla_s V_2(s,t) = 0 $. From here one can deduce that $V_1(s,t) = V_2(s,t) $ for all $s,t$. We can think of $ V_i, \; i=1,2 $ as a mapping $ V_i : (a,b) \rightarrow Vect(M) $. Then we can compleate $ Vect(M) $ in some suitable space, and from the uniqueness of the solutions of ODE-s it follws that $V_1 = V_2 $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample, consider $S^2$ with $X(t)$ is defined along the equator just by unit tangent vector, and $s$ curves are those connecting north pole and $t$ point along the equator, then $P_s X(t)$ will be the unit tangent vector along latitude-$s$ circle, but $\nabla_t P_s X(t)$ is not zero for $s>0$.

I believe it is equivalent to $M$ being flat, if $X(t)=P_t X$, then $\nabla_t P_sP_t X|_{(s,0)}=\frac{d}{dt}|_{(s,0)}P_{t}^{-1}P_sP_t X$, if we have commutativity, then $\frac{d}{dt}|_{(s,0)}P_{t}^{-1}P_sP_t X=0$ for all $s$, in particular, $\frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt}|_{(0,0)}P_s^{-1}P_t^{-1}P_s P_t X=0$, which means curvature is zero, see here
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Formally.